# How to do multiple brace expansions without combinatorial explosion?

Tags: bash, command-line, brace-expansion

I often use brace expansion on the command line, because it's handy.

#### Example

```
{foo,bar}
```

expands to:

```
foo bar
```

Multiple brace expansion also expand, e.g.:

```
{foo,bar}Q{foo,bar}
```

would expand to:

```
fooQfoo fooQbar barQfoo barQbar
```

This is expected behavior, where the brace expansions are used in order.

#### My Question

Now, I'd like the output of any brace expansion (or other short command line trick) to be:

```
fooQfoo barQbar
```

Note: I'm using `bash 3.2`

Comment: Do you really want `ls` to not report existing files, or is this [an XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Comment: @jasonwryan I thought I was clearly asking for a brace expansion trick, but I updated the question to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: Your edit hasn't made it any clearer to me. `ls` is a terrible example; tell us what you are actually trying to do...

Comment: I want to improve my understanding of shell-usage and brace expansion. It could be used on any command, but e.g. `vi -o dir1/file1 dir2/file2` or `meld dir3.2/code/vers3.2 dir5.6/code/vers5.6` etc. It is about command-line usage, not about any specific thing. Hope it is clear with my last edit.

Comment: Brace expansion just isn't as expressive as you want it to be; it was designed for a single, interactive purpose. There are other mechanisms that have the power you want.

Comment: @msw Which mechanisms?

Comment: It's too bad that Bash's `printf` and `printf (1)` don't support repeated arguments. Zsh's `printf` does (and ksh93 does, but it appears to be broken). In Zsh: `printf '%1$sQ%1$s\n' foo bar` (replace `\n` with a space if desired).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to get this done using only curly braces. I don't see a way to achieve this either, so unless someone more clever than I can figure out a way I'd say it's not possible.

#### As an alternative

Sample Data

```
$ tree
.
|-- dir1
|   |-- file1
|   `-- file2
`-- dir2
    |-- file1
    `-- file2
```

#### Examples

```
$ seq 2 | xargs -i{} echo dir{}/file{}
dir1/file1
dir2/file2
```

This can be put into a command like this:

```
$ echo $(seq 2 | xargs -i{} echo dir{}/file{})
dir1/file1 dir2/file2
```

or this:

```
$ ls $(seq 2 | xargs -i{} echo dir{}/file{})
dir1/file1  dir2/file2
```

or this:

```
$ ls -l $(seq 2 | xargs -i{} echo dir{}/file{})
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Sep  2 03:18 dir1/file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Sep  2 03:31 dir2/file2
```

#### Why curly braces can't do this

If you look at your original example:

```
{foo,bar}Q{foo,bar}
```

The way this gets expanded is as follows:

```
fooQfoo fooQbar barQfoo barQbar
```

The mechanism that expanded this is called a [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

For example:

```
$ echo {A,B}{X,Y,Z}
AX AY AZ BX BY BZ
```

Or this:

```
$ echo {M,N}-{A,B}{X,Y,Z}
M-AX M-AY M-AZ M-BX M-BY M-BZ N-AX N-AY N-AZ N-BX N-BY N-BZ
```

There is no way to create a Cartesian Product that will result in:

```
fooQfoo barQbar
```

You're only option is to either resort to trickery such as this:

```
$ echo dir{1,2}/file{2,1}
dir1/file2 dir1/file1 dir2/file2 dir2/file1
```

And then put this into a Bash array:

```
$ a=(dir{1,2}/file{2,1})
$ echo ${a[@]:1:2}
dir1/file1 dir2/file2
```

The other option would be some "other method" such as the one I previously discussed above (using `xargs`) for example.

#### References

- [Cartesian Products in Bash](http://automatthias.wordpress.com/2006/02/15/cartesian-product-in-bash/)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, the `xargs` solution will work in general, but seems too complicated for the simple solution I am looking for (see my edit if it makes it any clearer). I could take no for an answer if there is some reason behind.

Comment: @Bernhard - I understood you question before. I looked for a while to see if there was a way to do this and I still don't think it's possible. It's a limitation with the regular expressions (the braces) and the way that they expand. There isn't any way to limit them. So if there's a file and/or directory that matches the regex you've provided via the braces, there isn't anything in Bash that will augment the expansion. It's greedy. In Perl and other langs. the notation `.*` is greedy like this as well. However the langs. provide mechanisms for "controlling" it.

Comment: I was afraid for this answer, hoped for something like `{foo,bar}Q{}`

Comment: @Bernhard - here's an example if you want to learn more about braces: `echo {w,t,}h{e{n{,ce{,forth}},re{,in,fore,with{,al}}},ither,at}`

Comment: Haha, nice one, although it is only nesting :)

Comment: @Bernhard - yeah I thought that was cool. Never saw that before. Pretty impressive what you CAN do with regexs.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with slm; I've never seen a way to do this solely with brace expansion.

However, using the example in the question, I think the simplest way to get the desired output is to use a loop, rather than brace expansion and additional postprocessing:

```
$ echo $(for X in foo bar;do echo ${X}Q${X};done)
fooQfoo barQbar
```

Comment: I'd agree that this seems like the simplest and most readable option.